# How to prevent onResume() function not to be called on finished of its child activity

Tags: android

I have parent `Activity`, where I have some code written in `onResume()` of the parent `Activity`. Now, suppose I went from my parent `Activity` to one of its child `Activity`, then at that instance, my parent `Activity` is on pause. Now when I again return from my child activity to my parent `Activity` I don't want my parent activity `onResume()` to execute. I only want it to execute when the app turns off and when the app is on pause by clicking the home button.

So is it possible to do that? If so can anyone please suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a `static boolean variable isChildSelected = false` and use it.

on calling child intent set it to `true` and when returning back in `onResume()` check if `isChildSelected` is `true` or `false`;

if its true just assign `false` to it and if its `false` then run your SPECIAL code

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent onResume() from execution. I believe the solution is to move your code to onStart() (or onRestart()) methods.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks

Comment: I tried it using onStart and onRestart also..but it doesn't work..moreever in onStart() it behave as same as onResume()

Comment: If onStart() is executed, it means that onStop() was executed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to change life cycle of an activity as Vladimir said.You can not force stop to execute `onResume()` you can check that conditionor you can post your code in `onCreate()`